# Question on maximum consistent theory

Tags: model-theory, incompleteness

Lindenbaum theorem states that any consistent set of sentences can be enlarged to a maximal consistent set of sentences. Thus, by choosing a consistent set of sentences in Peano arithmetic and by Lindenbaum theorem, they can be enlarged to a complete theory. However, this contradicts that Peano arithmetic is incomplete. Any explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no contradiction at all: **the completion is not the same as the theory being completed**.

Peano arithmetic (by which I presume you mean *first-order* Peano arithmetic) $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent and incomplete. Lindenbaum says that since $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent, there is a consistent complete $T$ with $\mathsf{PA}\subseteq T$. This $T$ is **not the same as** $\mathsf{PA}$ itself, so there's no contradiction between $T$ being complete and $\mathsf{PA}$ being incomplete. (Also note that $\mathsf{PA}$ has many different complete consistent extensions.)

Now $\mathsf{PA}$ *does* have a "weak non-completeability" property: no **computably axiomatizable** consistent extension of $\mathsf{PA}$ can be complete *(this result is [Rosser's improvement of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick) Godel's first incompleteness theorem, and this property is called "essential incompleteness")*. However, this doesn't contradict Lindenbaum, it merely means that the above $T$s cannot be computably axiomatizable.

Comment: Beat me to it again

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Muaha - I say - ha. :P

Comment: @Noah Schweber, I think there is a problem. Peano arithmetic is incomplete because it contains some undecidable predicates. The completion of PA (actually) ignores these undecidable predicates and so there is no $\mathsf{PA}\subset T$.

Comment: @hermes "Peano arithmetic is incomplete because it contains some undecidable predicates." What? No. There are sentences which are PA-undecidable, but these don't *remain* undecidable when we pass to a stronger theory. There is no problem here.

Comment: Let's say, how do undecidable sentences in Godel's original paper become decidable in a stronger theory?

Comment: @hermes By being decidable in that stronger theory. There's no particular mystery here: there's no reason for the Godel sentence for one theory to be undecidable in a different theory. And in a complete extension of $\mathsf{PA}$ they *all* become decidable. For example, if we look at the completion $\mathsf{TA}=Th(\mathbb{N})$ we get a theory which **proves** every consistent r.e.-axiomatizable theory's Godel(-[Rosser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick)) sentence; as $\mathsf{TA}$ isn't arithmetically definable, it itself doesn't have a Godel sentence so there's no contradiction.

Comment: This is where I suspect. "as TA isn't arithmetically definable, it itself doesn't have a Godel sentence so there's no contradiction. – ", does not provide an exact solution to undecidable predicates but simply bypass it.

Comment: @hermes "does not provide an exact solution to undecidable predicates but simply bypass it" I don't understand your issue here. What do you mean by "an exact solution to undecidable predicates?" What's wrong with "simply bypassing" it? I really don't understand what you're getting at here, and I don't think this comment thread is a good place to hash it out; if you still don't understand my answer you should ask a separate question about it.

Comment: What I mean is that it does not touch the nature of undecidable predicates. The true nature of them relies on multi-valued logic. I can not explain more here. It has nothing to do with your answer which remains correct. Just the theory of complete extension could be inadequate.